# Debugger returning Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when using globalThis.import statement to load api

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am running a JavaScript (NodeJS) program locally in my browser. However, I am receiving the following error when the program is calling the APIs:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

The api import statement (there are two) are coded as follows:

```
globalThis.import finnhub from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/finnhub';
```

I should note, the specific character noted as causing the problem begins with the 'finnhub' part of the statement.

Comment: I thought I should add, I have included the type="module" attribute to my script section of my HTML. However, the problem still persists.

Comment: `import` is a standalone syntax, not a property of `globalThis`. Remove the `globalThis.` part.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to have been due to the globalThis. statement made prior to the import statement.

I should note, I had been receiving an error prior to calling globalThis. though. It seems to have ceased and the library calls are initializing.